# In jenkins, not able to build a android build

Tags: android, jenkins

In jenkins, building a  android app using "build --stacktrace". But the build is failing giving the below error, Please help

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
  >   A problem occurred configuring project ':wear'.
  >   No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mips64el-linux-android

Answer (score 0):

I think this thread can help you [link](https://github.com/google/filament/issues/15).